# General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 57

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx, desktop-application

I'm trying to setup libgdx for a desktop game and when I try to generate the project I have this error and the build fails.
I've the latest versions of Java(13.0.2) and Gradle(6.6), both set as environment variables in the path. Can somebody help me?

The error looks like this:

```
Could not compile settings file 'C:\Users\noemi\Desktop\Test\settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 57
  
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 57
```

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the 13.0.2

Comment: Oh I missed that. LibGDX isn't compiled against java 13 so there might be some binary incompatibilities. Can you try with Java 11 or 8?

Comment: I've tried and it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 33):

This is not a LibGDX issue. Gradle 5 is incompatible with Java 13. You either need to update Gradle (the wrapped version in your project) to Gradle 6 or later, or you need to use a lower version of the JRE.

To update the wrapped gradle, go to `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper-properties` in your project and update the version number. I'm using 6.1.1.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

If you have an older LibGDX project, you might have to modify the `build.gradle` file in the `android` module to be compatible with Gradle 6. You can copy-paste to replace the `copyAndroidNatives` task with [the one here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-setup/res/com/badlogic/gdx/setup/resources/android/build.gradle).

Comment: I've already had the latest version of Gradle, as I wrote in the question. At the end I've used an older version of Java and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, but by default the LibGDX project uses a gradle wrapper.

Comment: Id like to add that you can know the different version of gradle here: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Answer (score 28):

> startup failed:
> General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 61

how to fix this react native issues
JAVA JDK 17

Go to the android/ directory of your react-native project

Create a file called **local.properties** with this line:

> sdk.dir=C:\Android\sdk

GOTO
**android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties**

CHANGE

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip

TO

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-all.zip

GOTO

> android\gradle.properties
> add this line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.

Comment: react native Unrecognized option: - Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: Unrecognized option: - Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: This worked! using java 17.0.2 2022-01-18 LTS on Mac OS

Comment: Update gradle version to 7.3 helped me

Comment: which os are you using?

Answer (score 15):

This problem occurred when I run my old `Flutter` project that I coded 2 years ago. I think with Android project will also fix in the same way. I'm use `MacOS` and `Android Studio Bumblebee`.

First, need to move to the `android` folder and check gradle version:

```
cd android 
./gradlew --version
```

[image]

It show Gradle version `6.7.1` and you need attention to the JVM line, and my JDK version is 15.0.2. It is too new for this project. So you must to `downgrading` from open jdk version to old version or `upgrade` Gradle version in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to new version.

If you downgrade JDK version, you can download from [this](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html). In my case, I downgraded from Java SE 15 to Java SE 11.

After I open Android of Flutter project

[image]

Go to `Preferences->Build, Execution, Deployment → Build Tools → Gradle →`  and choose JDK version 11.
[image]

Go to Build -> Clean Project -> Rebuild Project.

[image]

Go to `Terminal` run `java --version`, if it still show JE version 15 then You must set JAVA_HOME before.

You only need to add the following to your `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.15.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Save and go to `android` folder and run again

```
./gradlew --version
```

It will show JDK version 11 correct.

[image]

Finally, run `flutter run`.

Answer (score 3):

I have downgraded gradle file thats why this error happens so finally I have to change Gradle wrapper file From

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip
```

Answer (score 3):

Java(13.0.2) and Gradle(6.6) are not compatible.

### Fix

You can either :

- change your JDK version to 14. Path to environment variable `JAVA_HOME`
- or keep your JDK to 13.x and change your Gradle version to 6.0 . In your project `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` , change the line to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-bin.zip` . [Available Gradle distributions](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

How to know the compatible versions ?

### Table Java Compatibility

Check this https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

| Java version | First Gradle version to support it |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 2.0 |
| 9 | 4.3 |
| 10 | 4.7 |
| 11 | 5.0 |
| 12 | 5.4 |
| 13 | 6.0 |
| 14 | 6.3 |
| 15 | 6.7 |
| 16 | 7.0 |
| 17 | 7.3 |
| 18 | 7.5 |
| 19 | 7.6 |
| 20 | 8.1 ⚠ |

Answer (score 2):

If you're using eclipse, go to

```
Eclipse > Preferences > Gradle
```

Update `Java home` to point to Java home location

Answer (score 0):

Check gradle version and bundle version using the following link
Link https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle

If you want to upgrade android/gradle/build.gradle change dependencies classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:**[latest version]**'